# Using testable free functions in code

Tags: ios, swift, tdd

I currently use a few worker classes in an app, which comprise of only one function.

The function performs the action described by the class name:

```
protocol FooUpdatable {
  func updateFoo(with foo: SomeFoo)
}

class FooUpdater: FooUpdatable {
  let dependency: DependencyType

  init(dependency: DependencyType = ConcreteDependency()) {
    self.dependency = dependency
  }

  func updateFoo(with foo: SomeFoo) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I am thinking some of these should be free functions, rather than in a class - but one benefit of the current architecture is testability. 
In tests, I can swap out this dependency for a mock through the constructor injection, but am not sure how best to do this with a free function.

```
func updateFoo(with foo: SomeFoo, dependency: DependencyType = ConcreteDependency() {
  ...
}
```

In Objective-C, mocking frameworks can do this through swizzling right? Any way of accomplishing the same in Swift?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know much about swift - but sounds like an interesting question. Balancing test-ability against clean code is sometimes not an easy decision.